# Sublime video player not resizing in IE9

Tags: jquery, css, html, video, html5-video

So I'm using this hosted js to run my videos: http://sublimevideo.net/

On the first slide here: www.xsp.com/indexvideo.php

The link is supposed to show a hidden div that has a  container. When you click video it is supposed to fill the space between the header and footer. Which it does. It is ALSO supposed to resize the video when you resize the browser window. Works in IE 7 + 8, Firefox, and Safari. But not IE 9.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Resize code to follow:

```
    $(window).resize(function() {
        proportion_index();
        clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
        resizeTimer = setTimeout(letsDoThis, 0);
    });

    function letsDoThis() {
        resize_object();
    };

    function resize_object() {
        var viewportwidth;
        var viewportheight;

        // the more standards compliant browsers (mozilla/netscape/opera/IE7) use window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight
        if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
            viewportwidth = window.innerWidth;
            viewportheight = window.innerHeight;
        }

        // IE6 in standards compliant mode (i.e. with a valid doctype as the first line in the document)
        else if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined' && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth !='undefined' && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0) {
            viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
            viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        }

        // older versions of IE
        else {
            viewportwidth = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;
            viewportheight = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight;
        }

        //SET THE VIEWPORT TO BROWSER WIDTH AND BROWSER HEIGHT MINUS THE HEADER AND FOOTER SPACE
        if(viewportheight > 650) {
            viewportheight = viewportheight - 242;
        } else if(viewportheight <= 650) {
            viewportheight = viewportheight - 90;
        }

        $('#slide1video').css('width',viewportwidth);
        $('#slide1video').css('height',viewportheight);
        $('#slide1video').css('z-index','1001');
        $('#slide1video').css('background','#000000');

        $('#sublime_video_wrapper_0').css('width',viewportwidth);
        $('#sublime_video_wrapper_0').css('height',viewportheight);
        $('#sublime_video_wrapper_0').css('z-index','1002');
        $('#slide1video').css('background','#000000');

        $('span.sv_play_button').css('width',viewportwidth);
        $('span.sv_play_button').css('height',viewportheight);
        $('span.sv_play_button').css('background','blue');
        $('span.sv_play_button').css('z-index','1003');

        $('.sublime_video_content').css('width',viewportwidth);
        $('.sublime_video_content').css('height',viewportheight);
        $('.sublime_video_content').css('background','#000000');

        $('video.sublimed').attr('width',viewportwidth);
        $('video.sublimed').attr('height',viewportheight);
        $('video.sublimed').css('width',viewportwidth);
        $('video.sublimed').css('height',viewportheight);
        $('video.sublimed').css('max-width',viewportwidth);
        $('video.sublimed').css('max-height',viewportheight);
        $('video.sublimed').css('left','0');
        $('video.sv_html5_fullscreen').css('left','0');
        $('video.sublimed').css('z-index','1000');

        $('.sv_controls').css('width',viewportwidth);
        $('.sv_progress_back').css('width',viewportwidth - 89);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to use the SublimeVideo resize method instead of doing it manually. Find a demo here: http://test.sublimevideo.net/resize and more information about the resize method in our documentation: http://docs.sublimevideo.net/javascript-api/methods#resize

Don't hesitate to ask any questions in our community forum.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I changed the functionality and used the listeners and methods and it works great.